# Open a window in a remote machine

Tags: ssh, remote

Is there a way to open a window in a remote machine via ssh?

I know that ssh -X redirects to my local remote windows but is there a way to open that windows in the remote machine and keep it alive after disconect (open it in a local-logged user)?

The problem is that i've change the amule.conf file to a familiar (because he can't find .aMule/Incoming, you know, i had to change the home directory path) an amule should be restarted (he has it opened in his desktop).

I only know how to kill the application and after it get X's in my local (that will be close with my connection: no cool) or let the daemon (amuled) in background but, if I launch the daemon, he will get an 'process already running' error when he tries to open again amule (if he dont see the window he'll think that its closed) and I'll get another telephone call...

Is ther a way to open it and let it in his desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is really not very clear. Why don't you have your friend open the window himself? Anyway, yes it is possible to `ssh` into a remote machine and open a graphical window displayed on that remote machine's currently running X server.

1. You need to tell your friend to allow you access. This can be done either by allowing everyone to connect to his X server:

   ```
    $ xhost +
    access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
   ```

   Or by allowing you specifically:

   ```
   $ xhost + si:localuser:eddieferetro
   localuser:eddieferetro being added to access control list
   ```

   In both cases, he needs to run these commands from his existing X session. He can then close it again by running the same command but replacing `+` with `-`:

   ```
   $ xhost - si:localuser:eddieferetro
   localuser:eddieferetro being removed from access control list
   ```

   Or by blocking all external access again:

   ```
   $ xhost -
   access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
   ```
2. Once he has done that, you can ssh normally, export the `DISPLAY` variable and run GUI commands that will appear in his X session (I am using `eog` as an example):

   ```
   eddie@local$ ssh eddie@remote
   eddie@remote$ export DISPLAY=:0
   eddie@remote$ eog
   ```
3. To make this window persist after you log out, you can run it with `nohup`:
       eddie@remote$ nohup eog &

   You can now log out with no problem.

Comment: I had to do it myself because it's not my friend, it's my father-in-law and he wasn't at his house (he let the PC on and I fix his computer when I can). If I let the PC like I get it there'll be less calls. :P.

Anyway next time i'll know how to do it, thanks again.

Anyway I wanted to know how to do it and I had an excuse... Thanks.